# Splitting a Text in JLabel with <br>

Tags: java, swing

Hello guys I've got a problem which makes my work too hard. I don't want to write  "br" when my words reached the limit of the jLabel. Does it have simple method to do ? Because my texts are too long and it is taking my time too much.

Comment: If text should go on more lines, you should use a jTextArea or a jTextField instead of a jLabel

Comment: Please check out the [many similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:+stackoverflow.com+java+JLabel+splitting+text).

Comment: @ddb: what is a jTextView? Do you mean JTextArea? Please remember that we are likely dealing with a newbie here.

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment, sorry

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I'm not newbie in Java I'm just trying to understand GUI :( But anyway thanks for your comments

Comment: I added JTextArea but nothing has happened. Result is same.

Comment: @Thorin: JTextArea will work fine, just be sure to call `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on it so that it will wrap your text. You also may need to fidget with its properties if you want it to look like a JLabel.

Comment: @Thorin: also avoid setting a JTextArea's size or preferred size and instead set its row and column properties.

Comment: wow! Worked amazing Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks

Comment: You're welcome Thorin